# List within list and lapply

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I have a list with ten elements and each of these is a list with 2 elements. This is part of what I get with str():

```
> str(results)
List of 10
 $ :List of 2
```

I want to apply the function **min** to the vector formed by the second element of each list, but I have no idea of how to do it with nested lists.

Example

```
results <- list(list(1, 2), list(3, 4), list(5, 6), list(4, 1), list(5, 1),
                list(5, 1), list(-1, 10), list(6, 0), list(0, 9), list(4, 4))
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `min(sapply(results, `[[`, 2))`? Does this get what you want?

Comment: That might be it. What does [[ do?

Comment: It just means extracting the second element of your sublist. Or `min(sapply(results, function(x) { x[[2]] }))`, they are equivalent.

Comment: Sure! Glad it helps.

Comment: or `min(unlist(results)[c(FALSE, TRUE)])` or `min(unlist(results)[c(TRUE, FALSE)])` to get the first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:

```
min(sapply(results, `[[`, 2))
```

or equivalently:

```
min(sapply(results, function(x) { x[[2]] }))
```